# Python, Google Charts with flask showing weird dates

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to create some charts with google charts api but i don't really understand what i'm doing wrong cause the charts are showing weird dates.
If i inspect the page the dates look fine.
[image]

Here the dates are looking fine 2018,12,23 and so on...

But the chart looks like this:
[image]

I don't understand why it's showing 2019-Ian-23? i thought that it should show 2018-DEC-23...

Comment: months are zero-based in JavaScript --> 2018-DEC-23 = `new Date(2018, 11, 23)`